# Is there a nice way to edit code analysis rulesets outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, code-analysis, fxcop, stylecop

As a former Visual Studio user, I'm used to being able to edit my code analysis (e.g. for FxCop and StyleCop) in the IDE. The [built in editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/working-in-the-code-analysis-rule-set-editor?view=vs-2017) makes it really easy.

I'm now using VS Code and trying to do the same thing. As far as I can tell, there don't seem to be any extensions for handling rulesets in VS Code. It looks like my only option is to edit the XML by hand.

Given that the rules are defined like this...

```
<Rule Id="CA2213" Action="Warning" />
```

I'm reluctant to go in and edit them manually if I can avoid it.

So:

- Have I missed an extension for VS Code that would help?
- Are there any standalone solutions?
- Perhaps an online editor/generator/wizard?

If not, I'm going to be spending a lot of time on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-warnings-for-managed-code-by-checkid?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Someone flagged this as off-topic. I consider this on topic because it is about "software tools commonly used by programmers" and is
"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".